# how to update Ionic's assets folder for existing installed app, without rebuilding apk?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm working on offline Ionic + Angular (Android targeted) App, where all data is displayed from `json` stored in `assets` folder.

Application is meant to work offline, but when there is update in `json` data, as of now I'm rebuilding APK to provide updated data in assets.

I want to update assets with updated JSON without providing new APK, is it possible?

Is there any feature of Ionic where user can upload new `json` file which can be added/updated/replaced in assets to refresh data without rebuilding APK?

I believe `json` stored in asset is part of APK package, do I need to store `json` somewhere else like

- SQLite Database
- Phone Memory / File Storage

or to update DB as well need to rebuild APK?

Please suggest best approach to manage this scenario.

Comment: APK cannot be changed because this cause a change in its signature. You can save files in App's folder and check if there are JSON files in it before fallback to Assets folder. This way needs a complete different approach in coding, so...

Comment: Use this plugin to store your data: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite

Comment: Thanks @emandt for suggestion to store in App's folder, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Assets can not be updated without generating new Build

If you are using cordova than you can try [Codepush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/). It's a great solution to push updates to apps

Or you can store data to Database and manage it.

Comment: Thanks @Vijay for sharing CodePush service, but if we have any other storage solution like mentioned in question, then like to go with such approach first

Comment: You can use DB to store your data and then if you change the data, it will reflect the updated data into your app. I suggest to use firebase.

Other solution is Ionic's own AppFlow service. It's like codepush but better.

https://ionic.io/appflow